# How do I queue files instead of simultaneously copying them with Windows?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, software-rec

Windows does not allow me to copy multiple files...
Well ofcourse it does when the files are in the same folder however it fails miserably when the files are in seperate folders.
Is there any utility tool that would allow me to keep adding the selected file to some kind of clipboard and then paste all of them to the destination?
Or does any other tool exist on similar lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php)** - Copy your files faster and easier

[image]

TeraCopy is a compact program designed to copy and move files at the maximum possible speed, providing the user a lot of features:

- Copy files faster. TeraCopy uses dynamically adjusted buffers to reduce seek times. Asynchronous copy speeds up file transfer between two physical hard drives.
- Pause and resume file transfers. Pause copy process at any time to free up system resources and continue with a single click.
- Error recovery. In case of copy error, TeraCopy will try several times and in the worse case just skips the file, not terminating the entire transfer.
- Interactive file list. TeraCopy shows failed file transfers and lets you fix the problem and recopy only problem files.
- Shell integration. TeraCopy can completely replace Explorer copy and move functions, allowing you work with files as usual.
- Full Unicode support.
- Windows 7 64-bit support.

Comment: I had tried this for a short while but I discontinued it as it would not copy some files, what has been your experience of using this.

Comment: TC is my first choice, nothing gets the job done faster. i was using FastCopy before: http://www.ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en

Comment: however, for what you have in mind (multiple destinations) go and get Total Commander, there is no better program. F5 (Copy) and F2 (Queue), can't beat it :)

Comment: Is there something Total Commander cannot do? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try [**n2ncopy**](http://www.freewarebb.com/n2ncopy-096-file6783.html):

[image]

Demo:

[image]

Comment: How do you rate this one? have you personally used it?

Comment: Works like a charm even on Win7. You simply add each file or folder you wish to copy by dragging it to the green box that pops up on your screen (a green & blue box will appear, green is for files to copy, blue is for destination folders). After you've dragged all files you wish to copy and confirmed the destination, simply right click the box and confirm the copy.

Comment: animation posted

Answer (score 2):

I use PikyBasket - which is a virtual basket in which you can collect files. Then you can copy or move the files in the basket in your destination folder.

I like the freeware older version - [Piky Basket 2.0 build 21](http://www.brothersoft.com/piky-basket-download-134827.html). There is a newer version also which is [available here](http://www.conceptworld.com/piky/piky_features.asp).

[image: Piky Basket Screenshot]

Comment: Piky Basket older version doesn't work on 64 bit OSes. The new version does.

Answer (score 1):

[SpeedCommander](https://www.speedproject.com/), available with a trial version, allows you to define multiple "file clipboards" that you can use to collect files from various locations and then do things with them - e. g. copying. Very intuitive and feature-rich. Copying happens in a separate thread with adjustable priority, so you can keep working while a background process copies your files.

Answer (score 0):

One can use [FreeCommander](https://freecommander.com/en/faq-file-operations/) to queue files instead of simultaneously copying them with Windows. To do so, using the [Queue feature](https://freecommander.com/en/faq-file-operations/):

> When using the [Queue feature](http://www.freecommander.com/fchelpxe/en/Operationsqueue1.html), only one operation is performed at the time, you can add the new operation(s) anytime, they will be added to the queue and performed in background, so you can use the FreeCommander during the operations. The Queue feature is available only if the FreeCommander file operations are enabled, to do this, open the “Settings → File/folder operations → [General](http://www.freecommander.com/fchelpxe/en/SettingsFilefolderOperatiGeneral.html)” and set “Use FreeCommander” option for Copy, Move, (and Delete). You can also use the option “Make Queue button as default in the operation dialog” in “Settings → File/folder operations → Operations Queue”.
>
> Note: FreeCommander file operations work only when using splitter bar Copy/Move buttons or F5/F6 hotkeys, they don’t work when using drag&drop, or Ctrl+C / Ctrl+X / Ctrl+V keyboard shortcuts.